# If not exist (*.*) not working on empty folder (Windows batch)

Tags: windows, batch, label

I don't think I have ever had this happen before. Using these commands:

```
rem    Check if any anything was downloaded...
if not exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :fail_message
if exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :continue
```

I can put a pause before those 2 commands and look in the `%download_temp%` folder and it is definitely empty, I have hidden files and "super hidden" system files set to show in Windows, I am logged in as an Administrator, the folder is definitely empty. I also know the download location being chosen doesn't have the types of files I am trying to download - so I have multiple reasons to know for sure the folder is empty.

Despite that, the above commands still skip to the `:continue` label instead of where it should, the `:fail_message` label.

Here's a quirk I noticed - if I change `*.*` to the file type `*.json` then everything works as it should, but sometimes it might not be a .json file, hence the use of `*.*`

I have also tried swapping `*.*` to just `*` but get the same effect.

Here's the entire batch file, there's no other `goto` commands before the ones shown above and I double checked the labels are correct:

```
cls
@echo off
mode con: cols=85 lines=40
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=160;$B.height=9999;$W.buffersize=$B;}"

cd /d %~dp0

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    This will attempt to download the Live Chat text file from a YouTube video / channel, from a copied clipboard link.
rem    
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
title Download Live Chats Before Date (From Clipboard Link)
color 0f

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Define a variable containing a single space character
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set GAP=%%A

rem    Set the input date as variables %year%%month%%day%
cls
echo.
echo.
echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo    Please copy the link to a YouTube channels "Video" page to your clipboard.
echo.
echo    Only Live Chats from BEFORE the date you enter will be downloaded.
echo.
echo    Please use numbers only, for example type 4 for the month of April, etc.
echo    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
set /p day="%GAP%   Please type the DAY: "
set /p month="%GAP%   Please type the MONTH: "
set /p year="%GAP%   Please type the YEAR: "
echo.
echo    Please wait...

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Check that yt-dlp is up to date...
start /wait /min yt-dlp.exe -U

rem    Cleanup from last time if it was updated while the process was running...
if exist "yt-dlp.exe.new" del "yt-dlp.exe" & ren "yt-dlp.exe.new" "yt-dlp.exe"

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Paste url into clipboard.txt...
set clipboard_link=%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
winclip.exe -p %clipboard_link%.txt

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Download Live Chat files to randomly named folder using youtube-dl (using clipboard.txt).
rem    Setting a "%RANDOM%" folder here allows multiple downloads to take place at the same time...
set download_temp=%RANDOM%%RANDOM%
md %download_temp%

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Download Live Chat to "%download_temp%" folder using yt-dlp (using clipboard.txt).
start /wait /min yt-dlp.exe --ignore-errors --skip-download --datebefore %year%%month%%day% --write-sub -o "%download_temp%\%%(upload_date)s - %%(uploader)s - %%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -a %clipboard_link%.txt

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Delete the now useless clipboard.txt file...
del %clipboard_link%.txt
pause
rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Check if any anything was downloaded...
if not exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :fail_message
if exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :continue

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:continue
rem    Create "NEW\Live Chat" folder.
if not exist "..\NEW\Live Chat" md "..\NEW\Live Chat"

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Remove non-standard characters from file names in the "%download_temp%" folder.
xcopy "SpecialChar\*.bat" "%download_temp%" /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
cd /d %download_temp%
call rename.bat >nul 2>&1
cd /d ..
del "%download_temp%\*.bat"

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo    Cleaning up Live Chat files to make them readable...
echo.
echo    Please wait...

rem    Clean up the downloaded Live Chat files with powershell.
xcopy "ReplaceText\Cleanup_LiveChat.txt" "%download_temp%"  /i /r /v /k /f /c /h /y >nul 2>&1
cd /d %download_temp%
ren "Cleanup_LiveChat.txt" "Cleanup_LiveChat.cmd"
call "Cleanup_LiveChat.cmd" >nul 2>&1
del "Cleanup_LiveChat.cmd"
cd /d ..

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem    Move the Live Chat files to "NEW\Live Chat"
move /y "%download_temp%\*" "..\NEW\Live Chat" >nul 2>&1
rd /s /q "%download_temp%\"

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo    Finished downloading Live Chats from before date: %day%\%month%\%year%
timeout 15 >nul
goto finished

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:fail_message
echo.
echo    Unfortunately this video/channel did not have
echo    any Live Chats from before date: %day%\%month%\%year%
echo.
echo    Exiting...
timeout 15 >nul
goto finished

rem    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:finished
exit
```

Cheers folks.

Comment: `if not exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :fail_message` will never jump to `fail_message` because `.` and `..` entities exists in any folder.

Comment: But it's only checking one folder `%download_temp%` - it shouldn't matter if there's files next to it or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

One simple line:

```
2>&1 >nul where "%download_temp%:*" && goto :fail_message || goto :continue
```

Or in two simple lines:

```
2>&1 >nul where "%download_temp%:*" && (
   goto :fail_message) || goto :continue
```

```
where path:*
find file without name ==> .txt
find file without .eXtension ==> file
find file with name.eXtension ==> file.txt
```

And you easily apply operator to check:

```
where "%download_temp%:*" return 0 to successfully case do ()
where "%download_temp%:*" return non 0 to unsuccessfully  case do ()
```

Comment: Most answers only address one case or the other; this provides both. If you're at the cmd prompt & want to test the current directory without a variable, `2>nul 1>nul where .:* && echo NOT EMPTY || echo EMPTY` or even the immediate parent `2>nul 1>nul where ..:* && echo NOT EMPTY || echo EMPTY`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it doesn't answer why the original problem happens.

The workaround is to attempt to delete the `%download_temp%` with `rd` (with no switches, so the folder only gets deleted if it's empty).

It does delete it, thus making the `goto` commands work as they should:

```
rem    Delete %download_temp% if it is empty (workaround for goto)...
rd "%download_temp%"

rem    Check if any anything was downloaded...
if not exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :fail_message
if exist "%download_temp%\*.*" goto :continue
```

Microsoft why u do this!

Answer (score 0):

Your test does not work since `.` and `..` exist in all folders and will be found
by the mask of `*.*`.

Here is how to check for an empty folder.
(The following code is untested.)

```
:: Is folder empty
set _TMP=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a /b "%download_temp%"') do set _TMP=%%a

IF {%_TMP%}=={} (
  set _empty=Empty
) ELSE (
  set _empty=Not Empty
)
```

Comment: Only one folder `%download_temp%` is being checked to see if it's empty. Using `rd` works to delete it if it's empty, then when the `if not exist` line runs, the folder doesn't exist at all at that point so it skips to the correct label.

Comment: Your solution works, but this is a less forceful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply.
"Harrymc" has right.
This is problem with "." and ".." entry in directory listing.
Formely "if not exist *.*" not "see" one dot and double dot in listing - so it worked fine.
Currently "if not exist *.*" always "see" one dot and double dot as files and directory is never empty.
It worked fine for FAT16 or FAT32, but not for NTFS or before Windows Server 2003 (I 'm not remember).
Many years ago I must change my scripts.
I use batch:

```
dir %1 /b/a-d|find/v "*.*">nul && (set fifexist=1)||(set fifexist=0)
```

Regards